# The element onClick handler conflicts with form onSubmit of sibling element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component which contains a search component with a form and onSubmit event handler and a menu list when adding an onClick event handler to the list item of the menu, the whole page stops rendering without any errors. I have noticed that this is conflicting with the form inside Search bar component, replacing that with an OnClick helps to render the page.is there a reason for not being able to use two different event handlers on siblings in this way?

```
    export default class Alphabet extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);

            this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
            this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
        }

        onClick(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            alert("clicked");
        }

        onSubmit(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            alert("clicked");
        }


        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <span>Alphabet</span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <SearchBar searchTerm="hi" onSubmit={this.onSubmit} />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li onClick={this.onClick}>
                                <span>Alerts</span>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>first alert</li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li onClick={this.onClick}>
                                <span>Help</span>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }


    export default class SearchBar extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            const { searchTerm } = this.props;
            this.state = {
                searchTerm
            };

            this.search = this.search.bind(this);
        }

        search(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            const { onSearchSubmit } = this.props;
            const { searchTerm } = this.state;
            onSearchSubmit(searchTerm);
        }

        render() {
            const { searchTerm } = this.state;

            return (
                <div id="searchBar" onClick={e => this.search(e)}>
                    <div className="searchBar">
                        <input
                            value={searchTerm}
                            onChange={this.onSearchTermChange}
                        />
                        <button type="submit" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

1. `const { onSearchSubmit } = this.props;`

But you don't pass any `onSearchSubmit` through the props.

2. `onChange={this.onSearchTermChange}`

But there is no `onSearchTermChange` function.

Have you not published the whole code?

3. `this.state = { searchTerm };`

Do you think it is a valid syntax?

---

And besides, you shouldn't store values in `state` if you already have them in `props`:

```
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        // Doesn't look good!
        const { searchTerm } = this.props;
        this.state = {
            searchTerm
        };
    }
```

Comment: I have tried to simplify my code, so please excuse the mistake on point 1, on point 2 as soon as i add the function and bind it, the page stops rendering, on point 3, i think its valid as long as that variable exists in code.